# e:Core data self referential relationships lost after application relaunch

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data

I am developing a Core Data based iPad application and have self referential relationships in some entities. I have to-many relationships without inverse relationship. See the image below

[image]

**Problem:**

After saving data when I fetched related products it gives me correct related products but when launch application again, it returns 0 related products.

**Update:**
When I created Inverse relationship now its working fine, but in my scenario i don't need that inverse relation.

**Explanation:**

I have a product A, which has products B, C and D as related product. 
But B don't have A as related product that's why I can't use inverse relationship.

Comment: are you sure you save your context before quitting?

Comment: Does the problem also occur if an inverse relationship is defined?

Comment: Similar problem to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763125/how-to-force-unidirectional-to-many-relationship-to-persist ?

Comment: Yes i save my context before quitting. I am running my application with Xcode on my iPhone 4S, after launching and saving data it works perfectly but when i relaunch from Xcode just relationships go away other data is intact, interestingly only these self referential relationships are vanishing other relations are saving perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete application from the Simulator or the Device.
Because using the same reference from the persistent co-ordinate will cause a problem in the relationship. 
Deleting app before relaunching will solve the problem.

Comment: I do not understand this answer.