# to-many inverse relationship fault fires when inserting a new "many" object

Tags: ios, core-data

(Xcode 6 + iOS 8 iPad Air Simulator)

I'm creating a new managed object in the "many" entity of a one-to-many relationship.    But it causes the to-many relationship fault on the "one" entity to fire.    Is this Core Data's normal behavior?

I have a schema like this:

```
Entity:         Parent             Child  
Relationship:   children<------->> parent
```

A Parent can have many children
A Child can have only one Parent

I create a Child in this manner:

```
- (void)createChildForParent:(Parent *)parent
{
   Child *newChild = <instantiate new Child managed object>

    newChild.parent = parent;       <- fault fires here.  Log says: CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "children" for objectID <the Parent> ... fulfilled from database.  Got 10000 rows
}
```

In my actual app, I have a task that creates many children for many parents.   Each time I create a child the parent's to-many fault fires.   Each time there's an accompanying SQL returning thousands of rows - yikes!  Instrument's Core Data Cache Misses is littered with RCM entries.    I don't expect the relationship fault on the Parent to fire because I'm only inserting a Child.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The relationship fault on the parent **does not fire if I don't set it as the inverse relationship** for the child's to-one relationship.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763125/how-to-force-unidirectional-to-many-relationship-to-persist?rq=1) is a good source of information.   This seems to be a standard Core Data behaviour.

I can understand that CD needs information regarding the children set in order to enforce the Optional and Minimum/Maximum Count properties in the model.   But I don't understand why it has to fault in the entire set even if I set the parent's to-many relationship to children as optional and no min/max count bounds (the default).   Sounds too extreme (and lazy).

Comment: Being a single-parent is hard. :(

Comment: Does it fire if you set the relationship the other way round: `[parent addChildObject:newChild];`?

Comment: @pbasdf: Yes, the fault also fires if I add the child by adding it to the parent's collection of child objects.

Comment: You could try prefetching the parents?

Comment: @pbasdf: if prefetching will help, I need to be prefetching the children instead, so as to prevent a cache miss whenever CD faults the to-many relationship on the parent.   In my test data I have only one instance of the parent in the database but thousands of children of that lone parent instance.    Adding just one child causes a SELECT that returns thousands of children.   I just updated my original post - no fault fires if I don't use inverse relationships.